# How can I compute the cumulative weighted average in new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Read all related pages on google and stackoverflow, and I still can't find the solution..

Given this `df` fragment:

```
        key_br_acc_posid  lot_in         price
ix                                            
1      1_885020_76141036    0.03       1.30004
2      1_885020_76236801    0.02       1.15297
5      1_885020_76502318    0.50    2752.08000
8      1_885020_76502318    4.50    2753.93000
9      1_885020_76502318    0.50    2753.93000
                 ...     ...           ...
1042  1_896967_123068980    0.01       1.17657
1044  1_896967_110335293    0.01      28.07100
1047  1_896967_110335293    0.01      24.14000
1053  1_896967_146913299   25.00      38.55000
1054  1_896967_147039856    2.00  121450.00000
```

How can I create a new column `w_avg_price` computing the moving weighted average price by `key_br_acc_posid`? The `lot_in` is the weight and the `price` is the value.

I tried many approaches with `groupby()` + `np.average()` buy I have to avoid the data aggregation. I need this value in each row.

Comment: What would your expected result look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupby` and then perform the calculation for each group using `cumsum()`s:

```
(df.groupby('key_br_acc_posid', as_index = False)
    .apply(lambda g: g.assign(w_avg_price = (g['lot_in']*g['price']).cumsum()/g['lot_in'].cumsum()))    
    .reset_index(level = 0, drop = True)
)
```

result:

```
        key_br_acc_posid    lot_in         price    w_avg_price
----  ------------------  --------  ------------  -------------
   1   1_885020_76141036      0.03       1.30004        1.30004
   2   1_885020_76236801      0.02       1.15297        1.15297
   5   1_885020_76502318      0.5     2752.08        2752.08
   8   1_885020_76502318      4.5     2753.93        2753.74
   9   1_885020_76502318      0.5     2753.93        2753.76
1044  1_896967_110335293      0.01      28.071         28.071
1047  1_896967_110335293      0.01      24.14          26.1055
1042  1_896967_123068980      0.01       1.17657        1.17657
1053  1_896967_146913299     25         38.55          38.55
1054  1_896967_147039856      2     121450         121450
```

Comment: Great. Seems to work. I just got my index back. I need it.

Comment: @DanielArges glad it is working! edited to preserve the original index

Comment: I just removed this last reset_index(). Gotta check carefully but it seems is correct.

Comment: ah ok makes sense, maybe the original answer was a better version then

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I'm calculating it right, but what you want is cumsum()

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lot_in':[.1,.2,.3],'price':[1.0,1.25,1.3]})
df['mvg_avg'] = (df['lot_in'] * df['price']).cumsum()
print(df)

       lot_in  price  mvg_avg
    0     0.1   1.00     0.10
    1     0.2   1.25     0.35
    2     0.3   1.30     0.74
```